# MySql - Round upto 10 in ORDER BY Query

Tags: mysql, rounding

My result's image is here(I can not post image!)

[Result](http://royalhome.ae/mobileroyalhome/images/Image%201.png)

And my query is here

```
SELECT * FROM `properties` ORDER BY CAST(price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) asc,
views desc,dateadded asc , liked desc,size desc
```

I want to get

1. Lowest Price
2. More views
3. Latest by date and so on

BUT I want to round price upto 10 like 504 is as 500 and 506 is as 510.

If we check our result, Id=8 has price 504 (so will count as 500) but very good views..so i want to view it on top.

**UPDATED**

I am getting this result,while i want record id=8 on top

```
id  price views dateadded  liked size
6   500     9   2014-12-23  7   900     
7   500     4   2014-11-25  4   1230    
4   500     3   2014-12-11  7   80  
5   500     2   2014-12-22  10  800     
8   504     10  2014-12-20  6   12630
```

Comment: You don't neeed to post images. Proper DDLs work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arithmetic for this:

```
ORDER BY CEIL(price/10) asc, . . .
```

If you want to see the price rounded up:

```
SELECT CEIL(price/10)*10
```

EDIT:

Round the price *down*:

```
ORDER BY FLOOR(price/10) asc, views desc,
         dateadded asc, liked desc, size desc
```

Comment: Both of them do not bring record id=8 on top

Comment: Try editing your question and showing sample data and the results you are getting.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to round 'up' or 'down' - just 'round' - as in SELECT ROUND(506/10)*10;

Comment: @Strawberry . . . The title says "round up".  The example says "round down" or "round".  In any case, this version should work.